# API gateway config file to call backend service URL

Tags: swagger, config, gateway, vertex

I'm trying to call a Vertex AI endpoint from an API Gateway, but I'm getting a null response when calling the API Gateway URL. I have the following configuration file:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: demo
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /predict:
    post:
      summary: Predict with Vertex AI
      operationId: predictWithVertexAI
      description: Predicts using a machine learning model hosted on Vertex AI.
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: key
          description: API Key
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: predictionRequest
          description: Prediction Request
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              instances:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    prefix:
                      type: string
              parameters:
                type: object
                properties:
                  candidateCount:
                    type: integer
                  maxOutputTokens:
                    type: integer
                  temperature:
                    type: number
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful prediction response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              result:
                type: string
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: key
    in: query
x-google-backend:
  address: "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/resonant-feat-398408/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/text-bison@001:predict"  # Replace with your actual backend address
```

```
API_ENDPOINT="us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
PROJECT_ID="ID"
MODEL_ID="code-bison"

curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:predict" -d \
$'{
    "instances": [
        {
            "prefix": "capital of Andhra Pradesh"
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "candidateCount": 2,
        "maxOutputTokens": 1024,
        "temperature": 0.2
    }
}'
```